# Function calls in a sequence

Tags: python, function

I am writing a program that must solve a task and the task has many points, so I made one function for each point.

In the main function, I am calling the functions (which all return a value) in the following way:

```
result = funcD(funcC(funcB(funcA(parameter))))
```

Is this way of setting function calls right and optimal or there is a better way?

Comment: it depends what you it to do. It is completely valid, but maybe not the best design if those functions are always called in that order like that.

Comment: Yes they are always called in that way. Any better way?

Comment: I think in this case you should use class and methods.

Comment: since they are always call in exactly that way ... the just call funcD with the `paramter`, and then have it call the other functions internally.

Comment: If only Python would add a function composition operator: `result = (funcD ∘ funcC ∘ funcB ∘ funcA)(parameter)`. (And yes, I'm aware of the arguments against it; I even agree with some of them.)

Answer (score 2):

First, as everyone else said, your implementation is totally valid, and separate into multiple lines is good idea to improve readability.

However, if there are even more that 4 functions, I have a better way to make your code more simple.

```
def chain_func(parameter, *functions):
    for func in functions:
        parameter = func(parameter)
    return parameter
```

This is based on python can pass function as a variable and call it in other function.

To use it, just simple `chain_func(parameter, funcA, funcB, funcC, funcD)`

Comment: @chepner The order of function be call is funcA -> funcB -> funcC -> funcD.

Comment: @chepner And the `chain_func` call each function in the parameter by the order that given in the caller which shall be `chain_func(parameter, funcA, funcB, funcC, funcD)`

Comment: Bah, I looked at that several times, and was still convinced it was the wrong order. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really wrong with that way. You could improve readability by instead calling them like this:

```
resultA = funcA(parameter)
resultB = funcB(resultA)
resultC = funcC(resultB)
resultD = funcD(resultC)
```

But that's really just a matter of personal preference and style.

Answer (score 1):

If what they do and what they return is fixed, then also the dependency between them is fixed. So you have no other way then call them in this order. Otherwise there is no way of telling without knowing what do they do exactly.

Whether you pin a reference to the partial results:

```
result1 = funcA(parameter)
#...
result = funcD(result3)
```

or call them as you've presented in your question doesn't make a significant difference.